# Logging unhandle exception

Tags: java, spring, logging, exception, slf4j

Write the application and I use slf4j as logger. Here is my configuration:

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//LOGGER" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="exceptionAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/exception.log" />
       <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n"/>          
       </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>


    <logger name="com.myPackage" additivity="false">
        <level value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="exceptionAppender" />
    </logger>
    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="exceptionAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
</code>
```

When I want to log exception I need to use try and catch but I have problem with not expected exceptions.
Could you help me with find the solution
How to loggin unhandled exception in my java code?

Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with slf4j. What kind of application do you have? What unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't catch and log Throwable?

Comment: @geoand catching `Throwable` catches `Error`s and `RuntimeException`s -- don't do that...

Comment: You're right, but I'm just trying to get a feeling of what's going on in this case

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think the OP wants to know whether there is a way to log exceptions which are not caught using a default logger or something -- given that uncaught exceptions go to stderr, my belief is that OP wants to somewhat capture stderr output and redirect it somewhere

Comment: It is Spring application. I not use logging abut the application is bigger and I think that I should log the exception to the file

Answer (score 0):

> How to loggin unhandled exception in my java code

At design time I prefer to catch all exceptions in a top base controller, but when the design of an application has completed this approach might cost to much work, so an aspect oriented approach would be more productive.

I see your question is tagged with Spring, in such framework there are some way to achieve what you need, you can use either `@ExceptionHandler` or `@ControllerAdvice`.